# What does kernel entry in Grub configuration file mean

Tags: linux, grub

I have looked at the GNU GRUB Manual 1.99 at (http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html) but I cannot find an explanation of what the `kernel` entry / command in the grub.conf file means. I get what's the meaning of that entry but where is described what it actually is and what are proper.

I suppose this entry / command was actual in GRUB Legacy, but I cannot find where it is described...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if [this](http://sheringeorge.co.cc/articles/grub-explained) helps at all:

```
kernel
 - Specifies path of the kernel file.
 - The root partition is specified as a argument along with kernel directive. 
 - This is is specified in conventional Linux format since this information is interpreted by Linux kernel.
 - ro tells the kernel to mount root file system as read-only.
```